# At what point does a Ruby project become a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I create a Ruby project that meets the required structure for a RubyGem, including a valid gem spec file, and host it in a Git repository, **but have not yet built it into a `myproject.gem` file**, is it, strictly speaking, a gem yet?

After all, `gem install` would not be able to install it, even if the `--source` option was used.

*NB. I realise that Bundler is able to install such projects.*

Comment: For people thinking of answering, I'd like you to consider questions like: would it make sense to call a Java project a jar if it hasn't ever been packaged as a .jar file? Would it make sense to call a C++ project an executable if it hadn't ever been compiled? My point is, a given Ruby project may have the potential to become a gem - may even be one step away from becoming one - but surely until it has been built as a gem, it is not actually a gem. Agree?

Comment: Why was this closed as not constructive? It may be a conceptual question about terminology, but it _does_ have a strict and precise answer.

Comment: I agree, Matheus. I think the problem is that three or four votes to close it arrived very swiftly after I posted it. My initial wording was not concise. However, although I completely reworded it, those votes were already in place. After that, it only took maybe one or two more votes (likely from people who did not understand the validity of the question) to automatically close it. I would be grateful if you could flag it to get the attention of a moderator who might be willing to reopen it.

Comment: [Since it is a documented practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130494/154407), I've marked it for moderator attention as you suggested.

Comment: The 'Git "Gems"' section of [this article by Bundler co-author Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) is germane to my question. I think it's telling that he uses inverted commas around "Gems".

Comment: Unfortunately, in the same article, I fear Katz may have muddied the waters in a different respect by sometimes using the term "gems" when he means either "libraries" or "libraries packaged as gems".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/), a gem contains:

- **Code**

  You can't have a Ruby project without Ruby code.
- **Documentation**

  Generated automatically from the project's README file and source code comments.
- **Gem specification**

  Project metadata.

Given this definition, one can see that the *only difference* between a Ruby project and a gem is the specification.

Actually, the entire packaging process *starts* with the specification:

1. You feed `gem build` a `.gemspec` file
2. It evaluates the file, which is valid Ruby code, and obtains a `Gem::Specification` object
3. It adds the files listed in the specification to an archive
4. It adds the compiled specification to a second archive
5. It creates your `.gem` file, which is nothing but a container for those two archives

When you open a `.gem` package, what do you find?

[image: Open gem package]

Your project files and metadata. Yeah, that's basically what it is: a glorified tarball with a whole bunch of project metadata included.

By itself, it's really no different than zipping up your entire project tree and putting it up for download, or tagging the latest commit with the current version and telling people to get the archive from GitHub.

The *only difference* between a regular software source package and a gem is that the *RubyGems software* is able to use the information contained within the package to provide automatic package management, dependency resolution, installation from remote repositories and so much more. The same can be said about other package formats, like Red Hat's `rpm` and Debian's `deb`.

While a `gem` is technically the software package itself, the noun is also used *informally* to refer to entire projects that can be packaged as a `gem` – projects that have a gem specification. Whether or not it has been pushed to RubyGems.org or any other remote gem repository does not matter because you can still use your specification to generate a `gem` package or to extract information about the project.

[Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/), for example, is a service that parses your `.gemspec` in order to determine and track your gem's dependencies, and it does so without generating or downloading any packages.

Comment: Thank you. You've nearly answered my question, but not quite. Specifically: do you regard the term "gem" as being synonymous with the *contents* of the package, or do you instead regard it as being synonymous with the *package itself*?

Comment: **"While a gem is technically the software package itself, the noun is also used to refer to entire projects that can be packaged as a gem – projects that have a gem specification."** Thank you, this is much more the kind of answer I was looking for! When you say, "the noun is also used to refer to entire projects that can be packaged as a gem," would I be right in understanding you to mean, the "noun is also used ***informally*** to refer to entire projects that can be packaged as a gem"?

Comment: @sampablokuper, well, I guess you'd be right. RubyGems is a package manager, and `gem`s are the actual packages. It's just that it's become part of the Ruby culture: Ruby 1.9 featured tighter integration with RubyGems, and eventually `gem` pretty much became a synonym for Ruby library. RubyGems literally became _the_ standard package manager; if you're developing a library, you're developing a gem.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a project with a gemspec is now a gem. Just because a project is not on rubygems.org should not preclude it from being called a gem.  Ultimately, rubygems.org is a repository of gems, one which you do not have to use.  A Github repo or any other repository can be viewed as another source.  I would also not require that the gem has been built into a Gem file.

Comment: Please note that I haven't asked about a criterion of *where* the gem is hosted (since the `gem install` command clearly allows built gems to be installed from hosts other than rubygems.org); I've asked about a criterion of *whether* the project has been built into a Gem file. I've also asked for answers to be *strictly speaking*, rather than informal, so please could you explain on what basis you would say that "a project with a gemspec is now a gem", unless the basis is simply that you're speaking informally.